# What does "golden fingers" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

I've come across the term "golden fingers" in a book, in the following context:

> Timing recovery has long been perceived as a field
> in which 'golden fingers' and intimate familiarity with analog circuitry are crucial.

I couldn't find the translation of this term or another example of usage. I should note that author is from the Netherlands. Intuitively I would guess that it means that someone can be considered very skillful, and in my native language (not Dutch) there is a corresponding idiom with literal translation "golden hands".

Is "golden fingers" a common idiom in English? If not, is there a proper term or idiom of that meaning?

Comment: No, but we have the saying "green fingers" for people who can make plants grow. There is a translation of Ian Fleming's *Goldfinger* into Dutch entitled *De man met de gouden vingers*. Perhaps it's a Dutch phrase, and so the Dutch author wrote it that way in English. We do however have [**magic touch**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/magic+touch) which means a similar thing.

Comment: I think we do have _golden touch_ too although less common than _magic touch._

Comment: @WeatherVane Very interesting! Based on your suggestion, I have found [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/green-fingers?q=green-fingers_1) couple examples that use "green fingers" in a broader sense. One of the examples: "He said his success in designing mixing consoles stemmed more from having green fingers and a very inquiring mind than any structured research process." The given meaning, however, is just what you said, regarding only the plant growth.

Comment: So the author may have been mixing his metaphors: Golden touch & Green fingers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dutch native speaker here, 'golden fingers' isn't an idiom here. Like you (Russian?) we do have 'golden hands' (see [this article in Dutch](https://isgeschiedenis.nl/nieuws/oorsprong-van-gouden-handen-hebben)); that phrase isn't used that often, but refers to [King Midas' golden touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midas#Golden_Touch).

As @WeatherVane suggests in the comments, I'd use 'magic touch':

> : a special power, influence, or skill that can be seen in the way something is done : an ability to produce good results in an impressive way

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magic%20touch))

Comment: Yes, I referred to a Russian term. In Russian it is not related to King Midas, "golden" simply has a figurative meaning "excellent". In conclusion I would also agree with @WeatherVane about a possible mix of metaphors in the original text.

Answer (score 0):

You’d need the context of the whole book really.  In this minimal context the author appears to be quite literally talking about ‘golden hands’ of the clock. The minute hand, hour hand and more likely the seconds hand. They appear to be talking about time in the opening line, and seem to suggest it involves the hands of a clock and some kind of analogue system.